# Cannot filter logged in users on the application_controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working with Ruby on Rails 2.3.8 and I want users to login before accesing any content from the website.

I've written the following in the `application_controller`

```
before_filter :login_required
```

When the app starts, I'm getting an error in the browser (not even from the application itself) saying it failed to redirect the page. And I see in the URL that says `http://localhost:3000/session/new` but it won't work.

Then, I've tried to place that filter in another controller, for example in `dashboard_controller`, which is the home page, and it worked fine (but it just works for this controller only, and I want it to filter in the entire app).

I then started thinking, and I actually think that the filter is being executed before the entry for one of these two lines are created in routes file:

```
map.login    '/login',    :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'new'
map.signup   '/signup',   :controller => 'users',    :action => 'new'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: One issue is that before_filter is one method, not two.

Comment: Ok, my bad. I wrote it wrong in the post, but not in the code, so that's not the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're redirecting without excluding the controller action that you don't want to redirect from. That is, your before filter is being triggered from the login page.

If so, skip the before_filter in your session controller

```
skip_before_filter :login_required, :only => [:login, :create]
```

Comment: This worked! I understand the problem now. It was like a circular redirect, so the browser didn't know what to do with it. I ended up writing the following at the sessions_controller: skip_before_filter :login_required

Comment: yep, infinite redirections, browsers don't like them :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to filter every request, only the ones requiring a logged in user. So put the `before_filter` in each controller where it is required instead of in `ApplicationController`. Yes, this means there will be some duplication (Oh, the horror!), but the intent of the code will be clearer.

Comment: I'm new to rails, but couldn't you create another base controller class that inherits from ApplicationController that has the before_filter code it in and then inherit from the new base controller for those areas of the site that require a login? You could call it SecuredController or something like that. Would that work?

Comment: Yes, you can create your own "polymorphic" controller classes. In practice I don't think this is done very often, because the actions tend to be distinct enough that there isn't a big win. But YMMV. In the OP's case, it's only one line of code being duplicated -- do you really need another class just to DRY that up?

Comment: More info about polymorphic controllers for those interested: http://www.pathf.com/blogs/2008/07/drying-up-rails-controllers-polymorphic-and-super-controllers/

Comment: The client wants to have logged users for all of the funcitonalities until BETA is released. That's why I wrote it in the app controller.